# get a wikidata resource in different language

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to get for a given wikidata resource its corresponding resource in other language, 
for example for http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/page/Q178794 resource , i want to get

```
 ar ساعة يد
 az Qol saatıbg Ръчен часовникbn    হাতঘড়ি
 ca Rellotge de polseracdo  
 fr Montre(horlogerie) ....
```

I searched and i founded that it's possible to request wkidata by its api or with sparql

How can i do that

Comment: I have no idea with wikidata, i work usually with dbpedia, that why i want to knwo how that's work

Comment: So you can already write SPARQL. Please show the current query first.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [wbgetentities](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities) API module to build your request:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&props=labels&ids=Q178794

Answer (score 0):

it works with :

```
    SELECT ?English ?language ?label
  WHERE
 {
wd:Q178794 rdfs:label ?English
; rdfs:label ?label .
FILTER (LANG(?English) = "en")
BIND(LANG(?label) as ?languageCode) 
?languageCode ^ps:P424 ?lstatement  .   ?lstatement pq:P794 wd:Q22283033    ; ^p:P424 ?wdLanguage .
?wdLanguage rdfs:label ?language .
FILTER (LANG(?language)="en")
  }
```